# parent div justify-content: center, last child align: left

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center align all child divs inside parent div. And it works if I put `display: flex;` & `justify-content: center;` on my `<parent-div>`

But the problem is - I am expecting the last child div to be aligned to left.
But `justify-content: center;` aligns the last `<child-div>` in the center.

I tried removing `justify-content: center;` from the `<parent-div>`, and added `margin: 0px 8px;` to get expected output. However, it is not responsive.

```css
.parent-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* margin: 0px 8px; */
  justify-content: center;
}
.child-div {
  border: 1px dotted indianred;
  height: 222px;
  width: 156px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "parent-div">
    <div class = "child-div">
        I am child 1
    </div>
    <div class = "child-div">
        I am child 2
    </div>
    <div class = "child-div">
       I am child 3
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: actual [link] (https://ibb.co/WV06M9R) expected [link] (https://ibb.co/c2qYf6S)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `justify-content` and specify `width` of the parent div.

```css
.parent-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border:1px solid;
  width: 316px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.child-div {
  border: 1px dotted indianred;
  height: 222px;
  width: 156px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="child-div">
    I am child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child-div">
    I am child 2
  </div>
  <div class="child-div">
    I am child 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did try that with width of parent div in fixed pixels and percentages, this is what I am getting https://ibb.co/cv1pGyc

Comment: Try to remove `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score -1):

Just apply a magic line to the last item `margin-right: auto`

```css
.parent-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* margin: 0px 8px; */
  justify-content: center;
}
.child-div {
  border: 1px dotted indianred;
  height: 222px;
  width: 156px;
}
.child-div:last-child{
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  margin-right: auto 
}
```

```html
<div class = "parent-div">
    <div class = "child-div">
        I am child 1
    </div>
    <div class = "child-div">
        I am child 2
    </div>
    <div class = "child-div">
       I am child 3
    </div>
    <div class = "child-div">
       I am child 4
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: umm.. this is what I am getting and it is not aligning with the rest of child divs https://ibb.co/RhRZdzj

Comment: You should to understand all child item always align center but the last child align left. That because the last item not align left same as another items.